# Complex Numbers: Triangle and Centroid

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles, centroid

> Show that $(z_1+z_2+z_3)/3$ is the centroid of a triangle whose vertices are $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$. 
>   (Hint: The centroid divides the median internally in the ratio of 2:1)

Comment: What do we have to show? (PLs. use MathJax)

Comment: Please let us know if you can solve from the hints given.

Answer (score 2):

Show that the point $G:=\frac {z_1 + z_2 + z_3}3$ is along the median line through the vertex $z_1$ and the midpoint of the opposite side $\frac {z_2 + z_3}2$ whose parametric equation is $(1-t)z_1+t\frac {z_2 + z_3}2$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$. The same for the other two medians.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I do not get how you get that parametric form, and no

Comment: How do you find the parametric equation of a line passing through two given points $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: I have only learnt the x=4ay and P(2ap, ap^2)

Comment: However im guessing it is like F2F1 rules, which will be y=f(x), then to let x=t?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation#Examples_with_vectors
Consider complex numbers as 2-dimensional vectors

Answer (score 1):

Note that from the hint and following [RobertZ suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2661503/505767) you should arrive to

$$\frac{z_1+z_2+z_3}3=z_1+\frac23\left(\frac{z_2+z_3}2-z_1\right)=z_2+\frac23\left(\frac{z_3+z_1}2-z_2\right)=z_3+\frac23\left(\frac{z_1+z_2}2-z_3\right)$$